# Wrapping legacy Application in Framework

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite, legacy

I have a legacy-Application with bad code and very untested. It's a large one and so we don't have the manpower to develop a new version in one step.

So I'd like to wrap it into a Symfony application and write the new parts in Symfony. The old classes will then be refactored step by step.

I tried to include the legacys frontcontroller in the application if symfony fires a 404. That works well.
But if i use the app now, i have errors with it's old routing system and symfonys .htaccess.

The symfony .htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

And the legacy .htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(css|jpg|png|gif|js|xml)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_shop_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The _shop_ Parameter is used for routing etc. and the Router of the old application depends on it.
Any idea how i can geh this together?

Comment: What do you mean by "if I use the app now" ? Also, what do you mean with "I have errors" ? Which errors ? How did you refactor your controllers code ? How did you catch the errors thrown by your legacy controllers ? Please give use details.

Comment: "if I use the app now" => if i call a URL which is not in the symfony routes
Then my LegacyController gets called and includes the index.php File of my old application.

"I have errors" => The routing of the old application does not work.
The index-page is shown, but when i visit /listing and have no symfony-route for this, then i receive a 404 not found. The old routing system depends on the _shop_ parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fix this in .htaccess, you have to define the valid routes.

Let's assume your old applications has the following possible routes and redirects:

```
/listing => index.php?shop=listing
/detail => index.php?shop=detail
/cart => index.php?shop=cart
```

Then you'll want your .htaccess to look like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (listing|detail|cart)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(css|jpg|png|gif|js|xml)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_shop_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

If this line is too simple for your needs, you can leverage the fact that in rewrite rules the OR flag has an higher precedence, and write something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^listing/something$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^detail/[complexRegex] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^cart/...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(css|jpg|png|gif|js|xml)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_shop_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

If you want something even more advanced, you'll have to tackle it at the application level (i.e. within index.php or app.php) and not in .htaccess